# Does year gap create any problem before Computer science(nlp) PhD

Tags: phd, united-states, funding, computer-science, covid-19

I  completed masters in 2017. After then I did internship as a software engineer in one  company X for 6 month in 2018. And then did another company Y job in 2019 as a full stack developer. But during that time(2020-2021) my family was infected by COVID-19, so insistly I quit my job for look after my family.

Consequently my family 4 members including me was infected. And in that time I  lost my elder brother.I was mentally broken.During this time in rural areas humans didn't have no money to survive, during that time I was started to help the people and teach the all village students and parallelly I have been started study very intuitively my personal all the computer science 12 to 14 subjects and try to contribute stack overflow site(Mathematics,computer science,Networking exchange,computer graphics etc) and focused on masters thesis. And the year 2022 I have published my research paper and parallelly started preparing for GRE and TOEFL. I scored 315,108 on GRE and TOEFL respectively. I have 4 gpa for both undergraduate and masters.I also get informal PhD offer from my home university where I did masters.

My question is could I get PhD admission with full scholarship in USA or any other university in world with full scholarship? I need the help and suggestions. In this situation what should I do by which I could get PhD admission with full scholarship?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, a gap year won't be an issue. It is actually fairly common.

However, "full scholarship" isn't a real concept for US doctoral education in most fields. Instead, most doctoral students serve as Teaching Assistants or (less common) Research Assistants for a stipend that includes tuition and is sufficient (barely) for a person with a small family.

But funding with no duties attached is rare in the US unless you happen to work in a field that is richly funded by grants held by your advisor.

I would guess that, from your description, that you could gain admission to a good US program with the gap year not a consideration. But make sure you have good letters of recommendation from your earlier studies. Funding may be more difficult and expect it to be modest and to come with some duties.

Lots of other places doctoral students are considered regular employees of the university. Again, there are duties attached.

Also see: [How does the admissions process work for Ph.D. programs in Country X?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/176908/75368)

Comment: "Funding may be more difficult  "-- this statement not understand properly?

Comment: Funding is a more important issue for you than the gap year. You will need to work that out with any university. Note that most doctoral students in the US have such funding, but it may be a bit more difficult for international students. The grading scheme you describe seems like India. In such case I'd expect fewer problems as your English language skills wouldn't be an issue. So you would "fit" in a TA slot.

Comment: When My Indian grade marks converted into USA grade points, I got both undergraduate and masters have 4 gpa. Thank u for your mental help. But industry experience certificate didn't collect from my 2nd company, they could ask for submit?

Comment: That "certificate" probably won't matter at all. Good luck.

Comment: By one TA, could I survive 2 people if we don't have any luxurious life style.

Comment: Yes, but a "modest" lifestyle. Far from luxurious. You'll be too busy to spend much money anyway.

Comment: TA provide 12 months salary? If not, how could I survive in not giving month?

Answer (score 2):

The gap year is not an issue. Especially since you tried to do something on your own (reasonable people in research knows that we all stand on the shoulders of giant, so being cut off from university&co no one expects from you some breakthrough coming from you on that period).

Depending on the country, PhD programs have no requirements at all with respect to age.

An issue you may have is about speaking and writing in correct English: I strongly suggest you to work on this aspect (English is not my mother tongue, I say this out of experience).

Other than that, the correct answer depends too much on the specific scolarship, so try to focus on some scolarship (get in touch with the relevant offices at the universities you aim to, they can be of tremendous help in navigating the bureaucracy).

Comment: One thing tell industry experience certificate could be verified by PhD committee?

Comment: No offence intended, but please, use commas when writing.

Comment: No offense, actually didn't not collect experience letter.

Comment: “Experience letter” is an Indian thing I guess. I’ve never gotten one in the ~40 years since my bachelor’s degree - they aren’t a thing in the US at all.

Comment: @JonCuster PhD committee can contact with my previous worked company as for checking I am responsible, brilliant person or not etc. ? Although I didn't lor from company.

Comment: Why would they bother trying to contact some random company somewhere else in the world?